# Qgis Plugin QgsMapToolEmitPoint QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature initialization

Tags: plugins, qgis

I'm working on a custom plugin in Qgis 3.22.3 Qt 5.15.2.  My goal is to have a tool run when I click on a button in my dock widget that can either identify or select features from a layer so I can pass those attributes to a database function. I have tried creating subclasses of both QgsMapToolEmitPoint and QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature and the init method does get called but the button 'does nothing'. Slightly modifying my code to create a subclass of "QgsMapTool" does in fact start the tool and responds to logging from canvasPress events, etc.  I'm still new to Qgis and figuring out how everything plays together, so I'm not sure if I can return features from QgsMaptool or not.  I would love it if someone could help offer some suggestions or guidance because I haven't been able to find clarity, and any examples I've tried modifying seem like standalone scripts that are run directly from Qgis.  Here is where my buttons connect(which gets called in init_gui), the subclass definition, and the function that gets called on button push. Code is very messy because of all the different iterations I've tried, but left it all here in case I have the right pieces.  Again any leads would be helpful.

```
def connect_the_buttons(self):
    # # get spots
    b = self.dock.select_spots_tool
    b.setEnabled(True)
    b.setCheckable(True)
    b.clicked.connect(self.getSpots)

def getSpots(self, checked):
    if checked:
        spot_id_List.clear()
        t = self.selectSpots(self.iface)
        #t = gs.selectSpots(self.iface)
        self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(t)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)
        spots = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('spots')[0]
        self.iface.setActiveLayer(spots)
        tType = type(t)
        log(f'what is t? >> {type(t)}')
        log(f'{tType}')
        log(f'type({t})')
        log(f'{self.selectSpots}')
    else:
        log('not checked')
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        spot_id_List.clear()

class selectSpots(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    #canvasClicked = pyqtSignal('QgsPointXY')
    # def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    #     return super(selectSpots, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        log('selectSpots __init__ function is running...')
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        #QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        #self.layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        #self.iface.canvasClicked.connect(self.id_spots)
        #c = iface.mapCanvas()
        #activeSpots = iface.activeLayer()
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        #self.iface.layer().connect(self.getLayerId)
        #self.iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(self.active_changed)
        #QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)

#     # def getLayerId(self):
#     #     log('connected_to_click layer event')
#     # # def id_spots(self):
#     # #     log('this happend when i clicked')

    def activate(self):
        log('The activate method was called.')

    def canvasDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        log('Double Clicked')
        log(f'double click event: {e}')

#     # def active_changed(self, layer):
#     #     activeSpots.removeSelection()
#     #     spot_id_List.clear()

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        log('canvas release event recorded')

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        log('canvas press event recorded')
        point = event.mapPoint()
        self.canvasClicked.emit(point)
        log(f'point: {point}')
#     #     log(f'event: {event}')
#     #     #self.handle_spot_selection()
#     #     log(f'on press: spot_id_List: {spot_id_List}')
#     #     # selectedLayer = self.iface.activeLayer()
#     #     # selection = selectedLayer.selectedFeatures()
#     #     #self.iface.actionSelect().trigger()
#     #     for f in selection:
#     #         spot_id_List.append(f.attribute('id'))
#     #         log(f'after press: spot_id_List: {spot_id_List}')
```